# Show one letter after another on Hover only with Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello i'm using the following code to display one letter after another on mouseenter.

```
function showText2(target, message, index, interval) {   
    if (index < message.length) {
        $(target).html(message[index++]);
        if(index == message.length) {
            index = 0;
            setTimeout(function () { showText2(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () { showText2(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
        }
    }
}



function showText(target, message, index, interval) {
    $(target).on('mouseenter', function(){
        if (index < message.length) {
            $(target).html(message[index++]);
            setTimeout(function () { showText2(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
        } 
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        console.log('LEAVE!');
    });
}


showText("#logo a", "Raffael Strasser", 0, 500);
```

My goal is to stop the animation on mouseleave and keep the letter of the current index how could i do this? Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8tptbLy/1/).
regards Manuel

Comment: [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Certainly will need [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is clear all timeout function `onmouseleave`

```
var timeOut, timeOut2;
function showText2(target, message, index, interval) {   
    if (index < message.length) {
        $(target).html(message[index++]);
        if(index == message.length) {
            index = 0;
            timeOut = setTimeout(function () { showText2(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
        } else {
            timeOut = setTimeout(function () { showText2(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
        }
    }
}

function showText(target, message, index, interval) {
    var timeOut;
    $(target).on('mouseenter', function(){
        if (index < message.length) {
            $(target).html(message[index++]);
            timeOut2 = setTimeout(function () { showText2(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
        } 
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        clearTimeout(timeOut2);
    });
}

showText("#logo a", "Raffael Strasser", 0, 500);
```

```js
var timeOut, timeOut2;
function showText2(target, message, index, interval) {   
if (index < message.length) {
    $(target).html(message[index++]);
    if(index == message.length) {
        index = 0;
        timeOut = setTimeout(function () { showText2(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
    } else {
        timeOut = setTimeout(function () { showText2(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
    }
}
}



function showText(target, message, index, interval) {
$(target).on('mouseenter', function(){
    if (index < message.length) {
        $(target).html(message[index++]);
        timeOut2 = setTimeout(function () { showText2(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
    } 
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    clearTimeout(timeOut2);
});
}


showText("#logo a", "Raffael Strasser", 0, 500);
```

```css
#logo a {
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo" class="columns small-12">
  <a href="#" rel="home">
  </a>
</div>
```